# What can cause a furnace to work worse

Tags: furnace

I have a 10 y/o trane xv80. It’s -3F in Chicago, and the furnace is struggling to keep 64F in the house, while set for 72. I don’t remember it being this bad in years past.

I had the furnace taken out this summer to repair a wall behind it, and it’s obvious from other signs that they did a poor job of reinstalling it. Given that, what are things that I can check that would result in poorer performance than years past? To be clear- it works, just not well enough or as well as in the past.

Comment: At a guess if the poor reinstall didn't attach the ductwork properly the furnace could be working as well as ever, just not delivering the warm air to the house. (Or removing cold air from the living spaces if the return is wrong.) It may be something more mundane though, did any dampers get closed accidently or the filter fouled from the construction?

Comment: New filter, and the ductwork seems correct.

Comment: An old dirty filter could be restricting airflow. Damage to ductwork can be a big one, especially return ducts. My mom had a terrible time heating her house until we realized the return was sucking cold air from the garage.

Comment: i lived in Chicago the past two winters, and this one is nothing like the last two, it might be snafu.

Comment: @dandavis yeah, but it's colder earlier, not coldest period.